# Question about finding volume using integration

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I need to solve the volume that's between:
$$z=0,\quad x=0,\quad y=0,\quad x^2+y^2=4\quad z=12-x-y$$

1) Does it matter if I use double integrals or triple?

2) When I draw this area on the x and y plane, I have a circle with radius 2. How do I know which quadrant my volume is in?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Does it matter if I use double integrals or triple?

You'll probably want to use a triple integral here.  But it doesn't really matter in this case (see qbert's answer).

> 2. How do I know which quadrant my volume is in?

You're right that the surfaces you're given do not specify one unique bounded volume.

[image]

I'd hazard a guess that your professor wants you to calculate the volume bounded by those surfaces *in the first octant*, but you really should bring this issue to his/ her attention.

Answer (score 2):

1)

No. You can set this up as either:
$$
\int_0^2\int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}zdxdy=\int_0^2\int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}(12-x-y)dydx
$$
Which represents integrating the volume bounded by the cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$ bounded above by the plane 
$$
12-x-y=z
$$
But this is just a shortcut for 
$$
\int_0^2\int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int_0^{12-x-y}dzdydx
$$
2)

You technically can't tell which octant you are in, but I think what was intended is as follows.

Assuming you are in the first octant you have
$$
0\leq z\leq12-x-y\\
0\leq y\leq \sqrt{4-x^2}\\
0\leq y\leq 2
$$

Comment: Technically there's nothing to suggest that the region the professor is asking for is in the first octant as you implicitly assume here.

Comment: hm that's true, I think that was the intent though